# Android canvas add stroke and elevation

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-bitmap

I am creating a thumbnail from a large image via canvas to use it as marker in google map and how can i add a border (stroke) of 2 dp and also light elevation in my thumbnail

**Canvas function**

```
public static  Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```